# what is the meaning of WITH (jsonContent varchar(MAX)) AS [result] in this code on azure synapse analytics

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I am not able to undertsand why we are writing **with (doc nvarchar(max)) as rows**

```
JSON FILE

{"date_rep":"2020-07-24","day":24,"month":7,"year":2020,"cases":3,"deaths":0,"geo_id":"AF"}
{"date_rep":"2020-07-25","day":25,"month":7,"year":2020,"cases":7,"deaths":0,"geo_id":"AF"}
{"date_rep":"2020-07-26","day":26,"month":7,"year":2020,"cases":4,"deaths":0,"geo_id":"AF"}
{"date_rep":"2020-07-27","day":27,"month":7,"year":2020,"cases":8,"deaths":0,"geo_id":"AF"}
```

My Code to open this JSON file start from here.

```
select
    JSON_VALUE(doc, '$.date_rep') AS date_reported,
    JSON_VALUE(doc, '$.countries_and_territories') AS country,
    CAST(JSON_VALUE(doc, '$.deaths') AS INT) as fatal,
    JSON_VALUE(doc, '$.cases') as cases,
    doc
from openrowset(
        bulk 'https://demoaccname.dfs.core.windows.net/demoadlscontainer/afg.json',

        format = 'csv',
        fieldterminator ='0x0b',
        fieldquote = '0x0b'
    ) with (doc nvarchar(max)) as rows
```

Comment: Can you share the sample data for the json file that you trying to read?

Answer (score 1):

jsonContent nvarchar(max) creates a external table with the column name jsonContent .

```
in 
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://XXXXX',
        FORMAT = 'CSV',
        FIELDQUOTE = '0x0b',
        FIELDTERMINATOR ='0x0b',
        ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0b'
    )  with (**jsonContent nvarchar(max)**) as rows
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`nvarchar(max)` in SQL can be used to store any string types. when we are loading the JSON from source to SQL table, we don't know exactly the length of the JSON and JSON is a string type.

In SQL there is no specific datatype for JSON so we use `WITH (jsonContent nvarchar(MAX)) AS [result]` to store JSON from file to `nvarchar` column.

JSON documents can be stored as-is in `NVARCHAR` columns. This is the best way for quick data load and ingestion because the loading speed is matching loading of string columns.